# Symfony 2/Twig translation text with html tags

Tags: symfony, twig, translation

I'm new in this community so tel me if I'm doing something wrong.
My problem is that in my website I need to translate some adverts containing some html tags, how can I translate only the text?

Exemple:

```
$content = '<h1>Hi</h1><p>some text</p>';
```

In twig template:

```
 {{advert.content|trans|raw}}
```

In message.fr.yml

```
Hi: Bonjour
some text: du texte
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Strart from here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html

Answer (score 0):

So I finnaly find a solution for this, adding quotes in the messages.fr.yml do the trick.

It's seems that it's not possible to translate word by word you have to translate all the expression.